# Azure web application deployment: Can I disable FTP on the public IP and enable it on the private IP only?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to disable FTP on the public IP of my web application by default, or do I need to purchase a web application firewall?  It's hard to believe that a basic firewall is not part of the default web app in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to go the route of getting an App Service Environment if you wanted to implement this restriction. I searched the [feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps?query=restrict%20ftp) and there aren't any plans I know of bringing FTP restriction to multitenant environments. An [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro) would be overpriced if that's all you needed and therefore wouldn't recommend it.